# How do I use vmlinux on kernel panic?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How do I use a *vmlinux* file to find out what line of a function source causes kernel panic?

Comment: Use crash utility ( https://linux.die.net/man/8/crash ). Common syntax is "crash <vmlinux> <vmcore>".  "dis -s <addr>" will give line number (for crash version >=7.1)

Comment: I don't get the _vmcore_ file.

Comment: do you have stack trace of process causing panic ? addr2line is another tool you can use to get line number if you have function offset.